# Android: Using Target SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, compatibility

I understand that the minimum SDK defines a minimum required OS level for your application to run and that target SDK tells the device the highest API version you used features from, assuming backwards compatibility has been implemented.

But that's what I don't understand.  How do you implement backwards compatibility for entirely new API features?

For example:

I've been using the old Notification system during development of my current app, not Notification.Builder.  If I choose to use Notification.Builder, will the OS or compiler automatically replace this with compatible code for platforms previous to when this was introduced?  Or do I have to check the OS version and write separate code?

Comment: You can leverage the NotificationCompat.Builder class in the Android support library: https://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

Comment: @twaddington good catch... didn't realize it was in the compatability library :)

Comment: Yeah, it'll make your life a lot easier. The base Notification class is pretty terrible to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to account for the new methods yourself, for example by using,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // Use methods introduced in API 11. (i.e. Notification.Builder)
} else {
    // Use old methods to ensure backwards compatibility.
}
```

A nice place to put these checks is in a utility class (i.e. `CompatUtils.java`). So for example, you might create a static method that takes a `Context` argument and returns a new `Notification`:

```
public static buildNotification(Context ctx) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Create and return the Notification using Notification.Builder
    } else {
        // Create and return the Notification using pre-HoneyComb methods
    }
}
```

Then simply call `CompatUtils.buildNotification(this)` within your `Activity` to create the new `Notification`. Abstracting out these sorts of details keeps your `Activity` concise, and is easily changeable if you ever need to later on.

Of course, it might be a better idea to just use the old methods to create your `Notification`, since you need to implement them anyway and the `Notification.Builder` is mostly just for convenience. Nonetheless, this is definitely something that you should keep in mind in case you run into similar issues later on!

---

### Edit:

`Notification.Builder` is also provided in the Android Support Package, so you should just use that in this case... however, for methods that are *not* provided in the compatibility package, you should use the design pattern described above.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense.  I will keep that in mind for future projects.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

google has its own compatability packages (in the support library) and there are also other third party solutions (like actionBarSherlock)  , and the Lint tool can tell you when you're trying to use a too-new feature that won't work on the API range you've set.

one way to check the API is using the android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT . another way is by using reflection , which sometimes google uses (yet i'm not sure why) .

in any case , google suggests in its videos to always set the targetSdk to the highest one that there is, in order to improve the optimization of the output APK.

Comment: I completely disabled Lint because it kept bugging out in Eclipse, coming up with syntax errors that didn't exist...

Comment: the syntax errors is a bug. you can do a project cleanup for it to be gone. of course , you can disable the automatic execution of Lint , and run it manually by clicking the "V" button .